# Step by step to making db connection in symfony1.4

Tags: database-connection, symfony-1.4

I'm new to symfony. My existing application is developed in symfony1.4. They didn't used any db connection. Now I want to create new MySQL database connection in this application.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. in settings.yml

   ```
   all:
     use_database: true
   ```
2. from the console run this command

   ```
   php symfony configure:database "mysql:host=dbhost;dbname=yourdbname" dbuser dbpassword
   ```

Comment: Yes Thanks for your advice. Then how i should call that in action class.

Comment: @Manivasagan Don't forget to [read the doc please](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine).

Comment: No, just run it once from the console and, as just said by jOk, don't forget to [read the doc](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/08-Inside-the-Model-Layer-Doctrine)

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the steps to make db connection symfony1.4

```
Step 1 :
```

file : config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php

```
find what:
---------

public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('owCorePlugin');
  }

Repalce with :
------------
public function setup()
  {
    $this->enablePlugins('owCorePlugin');
    $this->enablePlugins('sfDoctrinePlugin');    
  }
Step 2 :
config/databases.yml
You need to create this file and add below code.replace caps letter with your details.You need to maintain same space also.
all:
```

doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: mysql:host=HOST_NAME;dbname=DB_NAME
      username: USERNAME
      password: PASSWORD
    Step 3:
frontend/config/settings.yml

```
find what :
use_database:           false
Replace with
use_database:           true
Run the following command:
change the project configuration.Make sure you need to run this command in root folder of our project
```

php symfony configure:database --name=doctrine --class=sfDoctrineDatabase "mysql:host=HOST_NAME;dbname=DB_NAME" USERNAME PASSWORD

```
step 5: schema files
$ php symfony doctrine:build-schema
$ php symfony doctrine:build-model
$ php symfony doctrine:build-forms
$ php symfony doctrine:build-filters
$ ln -s lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/web web/sfDoctrinePlugin
```